# bash: if condition problem

Tags: bash

trying to do some operations on all the files in the directory that end in .c (C files). The code is:

```
#!/bin/sh
clear
for file in *
do
    if [ $file="*.c" ]
    then
        echo $file
    fi
done
exit 0
```

doesn't work. it just lists all the files and directories.

Comment: take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/407184/how-to-check-the-extension-of-a-filename-in-a-bash-script

Comment: you've a test problem not if ! see man test ;     in terminal run "man test"

Comment: changing to *.c in the for loop did it. Thanks everyone for the help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The condition on `if` is malformed, you're just checking that the string `$file=*.c` isn't empty. Try instead:

```
#!/bin/sh
clear
for file in *
do
    if [ "$file" = "*.c" ]
    then
        echo "$file"
    fi
done
exit 0
```

On the other hand, the comoding char '*' in this case is not functional, but it's interpreted to a string.

Try:

```
#!/bin/sh
clear
for file in *.c
do
    echo "$file"
done
exit 0
```

Comment: It most not be `$file` in the for statement.

Comment: Only a single ```=``` for POSIX compliance.

Comment: ... and put quotes around your variable substitutions i.e. `"$file"`

Comment: The if condition still only be true for a file named `*.c`. It does not check if `$file` ends with `.c`, does it.

Answer (score 4):

Your test statement does not check if the file's suffix is `.c`. It checks (in most cases) if `$file` is equal to `*.c`, see `test(1)`.

However, if you replaced your for statement to read

```
for file in *.c
```

the for statement would only be passed the files ending with `.c` so you don't have to check anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Another one liner way would be the usage of `find`:

```
find . -name "*.c" | xargs echo
```

It depends on what you actually want to do with those files  so that this helps you.